# How to find the arc length of a curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Given: $x=4e^tcos(t)$ and $y=4e^tsin(t)$ and a $t$ range from $0$ to $\pi$. I can find $$\frac{dx}{dt}$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dt}$$ and setup the initial integral, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: There is a formula to do this if you go to this website over here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx.

Comment: When you simplify the expression inside the square root, very nice things will happen.

Comment: There's a formula to use at this point $\int_a^b\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt$.

Answer (score 2):

The arc length formula for parametric equations is:
$\int^{a}_{b} \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2} \; dt$

Put your $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ in the formula and there is a good chance that things will simplify nicely, perhaps to a square of sin or cos that you can then square root. Think about using identities such as $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ and such.

Answer (score 1):

and we have $$\frac{dx}{dt}=4e^t\cos(t)-4e^t\sin(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=4e^t\sin(t)+4e^t\cos(t)$$

Comment: The OP said that they *could* find the derivatives already. So this doesn't really address the problem.

Comment: where can i read this?

Comment: What??? It literally says in the original question "I can find $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ and setup the initial integral[...]".

Comment: he can compare his solution with the solution of mine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's blocking you because once you set it up the integral is easy. Along the path the position vector is
$$\vec r=\langle4e^t\cos t,4e^t\sin t\rangle$$
So the vector element of arc length along the path is
$$d\vec r=\langle4e^t\cos t-4e^t\sin t,4e^t\sin t+4e^t\cos t\rangle dt$$
Then the scalar element of arc length is
$$\begin{align}ds&=\left|\left|d\vec r\right|\right|=\left|\left|\langle4e^t\cos t-4e^t\sin t,4e^t\sin t+4e^t\cos t\rangle dt\right|\right|\\
&=\sqrt{\left(4e^t\cos t-4e^t\sin t\right)^2+\left(4e^t\sin t+4e^t\cos t\right)^2}\,dt\\
&={\sqrt{16e^{2t}\cos^2t-32e^{2t}\sin t\cos t+16e^{2t}\sin^2t+16e^{2t}\sin^2t+32e^{2t}\sin t\cos t+16e^{2t}\cos^2t}\,dt}\\
&=\sqrt{32e^{2t}\left(\cos^2t+\sin^2t\right)}\,dt=4\sqrt2e^tdt\end{align}$$
So your integral should look like
$$s=\int ds=\int_0^{\pi}4\sqrt2e^tdt=\left.4\sqrt2e^t\right|_0^{\pi}=4\sqrt2\left(e^{\pi}-1\right)$$